How to add simliar reports as datasets to a MicroStrategy dossier?
I'm using MicroStrategy Web, and I am creating a MicroStrategy Dossier using three reports, two of which contain the same metric but use different filters. The only two fields in each report are "Account Number" and "Budget Amount", but the results are completely different for Report1 and Report2 based on the filters applied in each. When I add these two reports to the dossier, only the first one that I add will appear in the dossier's grid. What am I doing incorrectly and how can I get it to work as expected?

Just-in-case anybody else runs into this ... convert the metric with the same name in each of the datasets to an attribute. Then, convert that attribute back to a metric with a different name.
